# Proving there are always two numbers that have common factor greater than $1$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

How do you  prove that if we choose between any $12$ composite numbers from the first $1200$ natural numbers, there are always two numbers that have a common factor greater than $1$

Answer (score 10):

**Hint:** $\sqrt{1200} < 35$, and the 12th prime is ??

Then use Pigeonhole Principle.